# How to count class change within rows in html tables

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I would like to count class changed cells in each rows.

My desired result is like below.

are there any way to count?

[image]

Thanks

```js
 var $ = jQuery;
 $('.click').on('click', function(e) {
      e.preventDefault();
     $(this).toggleClass('aqua')
    })
```

```css
td {
  border: solid 1px black;
  padding:5px;
}
table {
  border-collapse: collapse;
}

.noborder {
  border: none;
  padding: 5px 8px;
}

.aqua {
background-color:aqua;}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>


<table>
  <tr>
    <td class=click>1</td>
    <td class=click>2</td>
    <td class=click>3</td>
    <td class="noborder"></td>
    <td></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td class=click>4</td>
    <td class=click>5</td>
    <td class=click>6</td>
    <td class="noborder"></td>
    <td></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td class=click>7</td>
    <td class=click>8</td>
    <td class=click>9</td>
    <td class="noborder"></td>
    <td></td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could do a foreach in each tr and calculate the tds inside it that have the 'aqua' code:

```js
var $ = jQuery;
 $('.click').on('click', function(e) {
      e.preventDefault();
      $(this).toggleClass('aqua');
      recalculate();
    })
    
function recalculate() {
    $('tr').each(function(index, tr) {
       let result = $(tr).find('td.click.aqua').length;
       $(tr).find('.result').text(result);
    });
}
```

```css
td {
  border: solid 1px black;
  padding:5px;
}
table {
  border-collapse: collapse;
}

.noborder {
  border: none;
  padding: 5px 8px;
}

.aqua {
background-color:aqua;}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>


<table>
  <tr>
    <td class=click>1</td>
    <td class=click>2</td>
    <td class=click>3</td>
    <td class="noborder"></td>
    <td class="result">0</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td class=click>4</td>
    <td class=click>5</td>
    <td class=click>6</td>
    <td class="noborder"></td>
    <td class="result">0</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td class=click>7</td>
    <td class=click>8</td>
    <td class=click>9</td>
    <td class="noborder"></td>
    <td class="result">0</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Answer (score 1):

Are you just interested in counting the cells with class `.aqua` or the number of times a cell toggles?

```
//number of cells with `.aqua` class
$(this).siblings('.noborder').next().text( $(this).parent().find('.aqua').length );
```

```js
var $ = jQuery;
$('.click').on('click', function(e) {
      e.preventDefault();
     $(this).toggleClass('aqua');
     $(this).siblings('.noborder').next().text( $(this).parent().find('.aqua').length );
})
```

```css
td {
  border: solid 1px black;
  padding:5px;
}
table {
  border-collapse: collapse;
}

.noborder {
  border: none;
  padding: 5px 8px;
}

.aqua {
background-color:aqua;}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>


<table>
  <tr>
    <td class=click>1</td>
    <td class=click>2</td>
    <td class=click>3</td>
    <td class="noborder"></td>
    <td></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td class=click>4</td>
    <td class=click>5</td>
    <td class=click>6</td>
    <td class="noborder"></td>
    <td></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td class=click>7</td>
    <td class=click>8</td>
    <td class=click>9</td>
    <td class="noborder"></td>
    <td></td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

To count the number of times the `.aqua` class toggles you would have to increment the previous value, zero if none.

```
//count the number of times `.aqua` toggles
$(this).siblings('.noborder').next().text( +$(this).parent().find('td:last').text() + 1 );
```

```js
var $ = jQuery;
$('.click').on('click', function(e) {
      e.preventDefault();
     $(this).toggleClass('aqua');
     $(this).siblings('.noborder').next().text( +$(this).parent().find('td:last').text() + 1 );
})
```

```css
td {
  border: solid 1px black;
  padding:5px;
}
table {
  border-collapse: collapse;
}

.noborder {
  border: none;
  padding: 5px 8px;
}

.aqua {
background-color:aqua;}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>


<table>
  <tr>
    <td class=click>1</td>
    <td class=click>2</td>
    <td class=click>3</td>
    <td class="noborder"></td>
    <td></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td class=click>4</td>
    <td class=click>5</td>
    <td class=click>6</td>
    <td class="noborder"></td>
    <td></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td class=click>7</td>
    <td class=click>8</td>
    <td class=click>9</td>
    <td class="noborder"></td>
    <td></td>
  </tr>
</table>
```